# Definition of mineralisation in context of organic chemistry

Tags: organic-chemistry, terminology, organic-oxidation

What does it mean when an organic compound, say [methylene blue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methylene_blue), is said to be *mineralised*? An accompanied equation shows the dye being converted into carbon dioxide and oxygen.

The only results I have found on Google are about soil chemistry.

Answer (score 8):

Simply put: organic → inorganic. Mineralization is often also called *[TOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_organic_carbon) diminution* (the term “*TOC reduction*” is purposely avoided due to ambiguity in chemical context). From Duffus et al. [[1, p. 1263](https://doi.org/10.1351/pac200779071153)]:

> **mineralization**
> Complete conversion of organic substances to inorganic derivatives, often visible as microscopic deposits which may be associated with damage to soft tissue (e.g., in the kidney).

Related entries from [[1](https://doi.org/10.1351/pac200779071153)]:

> **biomineralization**
> Complete conversion of organic substances to inorganic derivatives by living organisms, especially microorganisms.

> **calcification**
> Form of mineralization in which organic tissue becomes hardened by deposition of calcium salts within its substance.

> **complete mineralization**
> Complete breakdown of a complex organic compound to carbon dioxide, water, oxides, and oxidative inorganic products such as nitrate or sulfate.

#### Reference

1. Duffus, J. H.; Nordberg, M.; Templeton, D. M. Glossary of Terms Used in Toxicology, 2nd Edition (IUPAC Recommendations 2007). *Pure Appl. Chem.* **2007**, 79 (7). DOI: [10.1351/pac200779071153](https://doi.org/10.1351/pac200779071153). (Free Access)